Fast Way to Convert BufferedImage Pixels with a Specific Color into an Area
I am making an image editing application using Java and would like to make a select-by-color tool. A select-by-color tool makes my variable selection, a subclass of Area, highlight pixels in the selected image based on whether or not they are a specific color, an int. In this code snippet selectedImage is the BufferedImage that is used to create the Area.
int selectedColor = selectedImage.getRGB(...based on MouseEvent...);
for(int x = 0 ; x < selectedImage.getWidth() ; x++){
    for(int y = 0 ; y < selectedImage.getHeight() ; y++){
        if(selectedImage.getRGB(x, y) == selectedColor){
            selection.add(new Area(new Rectangle(x, y, 1, 1)));
        }
    }
}

I didn't really find anything useful that resolves my problem on StackOverflow or in the Oracle Docs. I found LookUpOp, which is almost capable of what I'm looing for but it only works by converting BufferedImages and I can't turn it into an Area.
This code works, however it is too slow to be an acceptable way of making the tool work.
EDIT:
I tried using the answer matt gave me, and my code looks like this:
(path is a Path2D object)
int selectedColor = selectedImage.getRGB(...based on MouseEvent...);
        
for(int x = 0 ; x < selectedImage.getWidth() ; x++){
    for(int y = 0 ; y < selectedImage.getHeight() ; y++){
        if(selectedImage.getRGB(x, y) == selectedColor){
            path.append(new Rectangle(x, y, 1, 1), false);
        }
    }
}
selection = new SelectionArea(path);

But it's still too slow. My computer specs are:
3.6 gH processor
8 GB of RAM
There is nothing in the SelectionArea constructor that should make it slow.

Which part is slow? selectImage.getRGB(x,y) is going to be slow. It is faster to get the raster and the pixel array and grab the values directly. That might not be the bottleneck though, is the area building slow? You could use a profiler to see which is consuming the most time. Or you can replace each with a dummy operation.

Usually, when a problem like this arises in my code, it involves the
selection.add(new Area(new Rectangle())); because it has to instantiate those objects.  A pixel array could potentially help however, I am not 100% sure which part of my code is more costly to the CPU.

I'm afraid the only way to fix this problem is to use a Path2D and do raster-to-vector conversion. This link gave me some ideas as to how to implement that: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/10824000809480639

Minor improvement: Swap the x and y loop. You should always loop over x/width in the inner loop, because these pixel values are closer in distance and more likely already in cache. Another simple/naive improvement: Create a single Area for adjacent pixels.

First, did you profile? That is the most important part, find the bottle neck. If you sit there and work on a solution, only to find it doesn't work because the actual bottle neck was something else it's better to check sooner than later. Second, why are you using an area? Your subclassing area already, instead implement shape and make it efficient where you need it.

I made a script to profile this. I found the rgb look up and the order of iterations to be irrelevant compared to updating the Area. As you suggested a Path2D can significantly improve the results.
package orpal;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Random;

public class PixelPaths {
    static int w = 1920;
    static int h = 1024;
    Random ng = new Random(42);
    BufferedImage current = generateImage();
    Area selected = new Area();
    static class Result{
        Path2D p = new Path2D.Double();
        int count = 0;
        public Result(){

        }
        public void add(Shape s){
            p.append(s, false);
        }
        public Area build(){
            return new Area(p);
        }
    }

    BufferedImage generateImage(){
        int boxes = 1500;
        int size = 25;
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)img.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        for(int i = 0; i<boxes; i++){
            int x = (int)(ng.nextDouble()*w);
            int y = (int)(ng.nextDouble()*h);
            int wi = (int)Math.abs(ng.nextGaussian(0, size));
            int hi = (int)Math.abs(ng.nextGaussian(0, size));
            g.fillRect(x, y, wi, hi);
        }
        g.dispose();
        return img;
    }
    public Area generateArea(Point2D pt, BufferedImage img){
        Result result = new Result();
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        int chosen = img.getRGB((int)pt.getX(), (int)pt.getY());
        for(int i = 0; i<w; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<h; j++){
                //int p = pixels[j*w + i];
                int p = img.getRGB(i, j);
                if(p == chosen){
                    result.add( new Rectangle(i, j, 1, 1) );
                }
            }
        }
        long path2d = System.nanoTime();
        Area finished = result.build();
        long finish = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println("path2d: " + (path2d - start)*1e-9 + "area: " + (finish - path2d)*1e-9  + " seconds");
        return finished;
    }

    public void buildGui(){
        current = generateImage();
        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(current)){
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                ((Graphics2D)g).draw(selected);
            }
        };
        label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                Point2D pt = e.getPoint();
                SwingWorker<Area, BufferedImage> s = new SwingWorker<>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Area doInBackground() throws Exception {
                        BufferedImage img = generateImage();
                        publish(img);
                        return generateArea(pt, img);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void done(){
                        try {
                            selected = get();
                            label.repaint();
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void process(java.util.List<BufferedImage> imgs){
                        current = imgs.get(0);
                        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(current));
                    }
                };
                s.execute();
            }
        });
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Vector to Path");
        frame.add(label);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        PixelPaths pp = new PixelPaths();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(pp::buildGui);
    }
}


This went from a 4.5 second runtime to a fraction of a second for 512x512. It seemed to scale linearly with larger images. It takes about 1.3s for a 2048 x 2048.
Changing the order of iteration, ie iterating over j in the outer loop didn't do anything for the speed of the look up/image but it did affect the area.add(new Area(...)); call going from 6s to 4s.
I've updated the example to be somewhat interactive.

I tried your code in a test package, and it worked, and was fast, but when I tried applying it to my code, it was still too slow to function. I posted an edit, and showed how I tried applying your code to mine, and I don't see the difference as to why it isn't any faster. Any ideas?

@TheDogontheLog how big is the image? How slow is too slow? You're doing this on the EDT it appears, so it will block your gui until it finishes. Did you check the time it takes? Is your image a different type?

The image is 1920x1080. Slow is taking more than 3-5 seconds. I am doing this on the EDT. Should I multithread the loading of the process so my GUI can keep loading? I didn't check what time it took because it was too slow already. I left it running for at least 30 seconds to no avail. My image is BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB

You're saying it takes more than 30 seconds in your application? I suspect the bottleneck is elsewhere then. Are you sure that it is taking so long in the path building and conversion to an area? You should include some profiling statements. If you use a swingworker you can start the action, and then publish the results when the action finishes and it won't lag your gui.

I think there is nothing else that could be bottlenecking it because the method call comes from a MouseListener's MouseEvent. What exactly do you mean by "profiling statements"? Thank you for the idea of the SwingWorker.

I think it was because I was trying to select the bigger part of a 1920x1080 canvas that it took so long. If I select a small area and bucket fill it, deselect it, and then use the ColorSelectTool, it works in about 3-5 seconds. I'd still like to make it faster than that but I'm not sure how to simplify my code anymore. Is there some way to do it without doing it pixel-by-pixel?

I have a similar function in another class that does a bucket fill algorithm pixel-by-pixel using setRGB() that is not slow at all. This leads me to conclude that the bottleneck is coming out of Path2D.

I mean to put long start = System.nanoTime(); before an action and check how long it takes after. For me building the path2d takes about 30% of the time compared to generating the area. Ill update this example. I played with a couple different scenerios and I think worse case was ~3 seconds for a 2048x2048. Ill update this example.

@TheDogontheLog I have updated the example. Now you click on the image and it will generate a new image and find the paths. Pretty consistently the path2d is faster than generating the area. It never takes over 2 seconds. I've also included the swing worker bits. I suspect if your going over 10 seconds something is going wrong. Also, why do you need an area. Could you use a binary image instead? You could perform an image opp incredibly fast. Then you can check 'contains' and draw the boundary also incredibly fast.

It may be hard to get the Area class to perform well enough for this task.
Here is an alternative implementation that calculates the shape in less than .03s on my Mac using Java 19.
This uses my ShapeTracer class, which is available here:
https://github.com/mickleness/pumpernickel/blob/master/src/main/java/com/pump/awt/ShapeTracer.java
package orpal;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputAdapter;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPanelUI;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.awt.geom.PathIterator;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Random;

public class PixelPaths {
    static int w = 1920;
    static int h = 1024;
    Random ng = new Random(42);
    BufferedImage current;
    Shape outline;

    BufferedImage generateImage(){
        int boxes = 1500;
        int size = 25;
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)img.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        for(int i = 0; i<boxes; i++){
            int x = (int)(ng.nextDouble()*w);
            int y = (int)(ng.nextDouble()*h);
            int wi = (int)Math.abs(ng.nextGaussian(0, size));
            int hi = (int)Math.abs(ng.nextGaussian(0, size));
            switch(ng.nextInt(3)) {
                case 0:
                    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    g.setColor(Color.RED);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                    break;
            }
            g.fillRect(x, y, wi, hi);
        }
        g.dispose();
        return img;
    }

    public void buildGui(){
        current = generateImage();
        JPanel imagePanel = new JPanel();
        imagePanel.setUI(new BasicPanelUI() {
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
                g.drawImage(current, 0, 0, null);
                if (outline != null) {
                    g.setColor(Color.white);
                    ((Graphics2D)g).draw(outline);
                }
            }
        });
        imagePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w, h));

        MouseInputAdapter mouseInputAdapter = new MouseInputAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                current = generateImage();
                outline = null;
                imagePanel.repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                int clickedPixel = current.getRGB(e.getX(), e.getY());
                System.out.println("mouseMoved over pixel #" + Integer.toUnsignedString(clickedPixel, 16));

                long startTime = System.nanoTime();
                ShapeTracer tracer = new ShapeTracer() {
                    @Override
                    protected void createPixelMask(int[] pixels, int width, int height) {
                        for (int k = 0; k < pixels.length; k++) {
                            pixels[k] = (pixels[k] == clickedPixel) ? PIXEL_INCLUDE : 0;
                        }
                    }
                };
                outline = tracer.trace(current);
                imagePanel.repaint();

                long endTime = System.nanoTime();
                System.out.println("shape creation: " + (endTime - startTime)*1e-9 + " seconds");
            }
        };
        imagePanel.addMouseListener(mouseInputAdapter);
        imagePanel.addMouseMotionListener(mouseInputAdapter);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Vector to Path");
        frame.add(imagePanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        PixelPaths pp = new PixelPaths();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(pp::buildGui);
    }
}

/**
 * This converts a region of pixels into a <code>java.awt.Shape</code>. The
 * shape is intended to be blocky/pixelated; if you want to smooth the data out
 * you'll have to smooth the shape out separately.
 * <p>
 * This could be used for flood fill painter, a magic wand selection, or any
 * other feature that requires creating a mask from an image.
 */
class ShapeTracer {

    /**
     * This collapses collinear horizontal and vertical points. For example, if
     * you add (0,0), (1,0) and (2,0) to this polygon, then it will only record
     * (0,0) and (2,0).
     * <p>
     * (This object is expected only ever receive orthogonally collinear points,
     * so that's all it's designed to collapse.)
     */
    static class CollapsedPolygon extends Polygon {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void addPoint(int x, int y) {
            if (npoints > 0 && xpoints[npoints - 1] == x
                    && ypoints[npoints - 1] == y)
                return;
            if (npoints > 1) {
                int xMinus2 = xpoints[npoints - 2];
                int yMinus2 = ypoints[npoints - 2];
                int xMinus1 = xpoints[npoints - 1];
                int yMinus1 = ypoints[npoints - 1];
                if (xMinus2 == xMinus1 && xMinus1 == x) {
                    // we have a vertical line
                    if (yMinus2 < yMinus1 && yMinus1 < y) {
                        ypoints[npoints - 1] = y;
                        invalidate();
                        return;
                    } else if (y < yMinus1 && yMinus1 < yMinus2) {
                        ypoints[npoints - 1] = y;
                        invalidate();
                        return;
                    }
                } else if (yMinus2 == yMinus1 && yMinus1 == y) {
                    // we have a horizonal line
                    if (xMinus2 < xMinus1 && xMinus1 < x) {
                        xpoints[npoints - 1] = x;
                        invalidate();
                        return;
                    } else if (x < xMinus1 && xMinus1 < xMinus2) {
                        xpoints[npoints - 1] = x;
                        invalidate();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            super.addPoint(x, y);
        }

    }

    /**
     * This mask indicates a pixel should be included in the resulting shape.
     */
    protected static final int PIXEL_INCLUDE = 1;

    /**
     * This mask indicates a pixel value has a top edge we need to trace.
     */
    private static final int EDGE_TOP = 2;

    /**
     * This mask indicates a pixel value has a left edge we need to trace.
     */
    private static final int EDGE_LEFT = 4;

    /**
     * Create a shape based on an image.
     * <p>
     * The default implementation traces mostly opaque pixels, but you can
     * modify this by overriding {@link #createPixelMask(int[], int, int)}.
     *
     * @param img
     *            the image to trace zero or more shapes from.
     * @return a shape outline parts of the images provided.
     */
    public Shape trace(BufferedImage img) {
        // add 1 px to the right/bottom edge
        int width = img.getWidth() + 1;
        int height = img.getHeight() + 1;
        int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
        img.getRGB(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), pixels, 0, width);

        createPixelMask(pixels, width, height);

        int k = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++, k++) {
                if ((pixels[k] & PIXEL_INCLUDE) == 1) {
                    if (x - 1 >= 0 && (pixels[k - 1] & PIXEL_INCLUDE) == 0
                            || x == 0) {
                        pixels[k] += EDGE_LEFT;
                    }
                    if (x + 1 < width && (pixels[k + 1] & PIXEL_INCLUDE) == 0) {
                        pixels[k + 1] += EDGE_LEFT;
                    }

                    if (y - 1 >= 0 && (pixels[k - width] & PIXEL_INCLUDE) == 0
                            || y == 0) {
                        pixels[k] += EDGE_TOP;
                    }
                    if (y + 1 < height
                            && (pixels[k + width] & PIXEL_INCLUDE) == 0) {
                        pixels[k + width] += EDGE_TOP;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Path2D path = new Path2D.Float(PathIterator.WIND_EVEN_ODD);

        k = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++, k++) {
                int v = pixels[k];
                if ((v & EDGE_TOP) != 0) {
                    Polygon p = tracePath(pixels, width, height, x, y);
                    path.append(p, false);
                }
            }
        }

        return path;
    }

    /**
     * This replaces every ARGB pixel value with a value of PIXEL_INCLUDE or
     * zero.
     * <p>
     * The default implementation sets every pixel with an alpha value greater
     * than 250 to PIXEL_INCLUDE and sets every other pixel to zero.
     * <p>
     * This method is a hook for subclasses to customize exactly which pixels
     * are traced.
     *
     * @param pixels
     *            the ARGB pixel data this object is responsible for converting
     *            into shapes.
     * @param width
     *            the width of the ARGB image. Note this is 1 pixel wider than
     *            the image passed to {@link #trace(BufferedImage)} (the extra
     *            column is empty).
     * @param height
     *            the height of the ARGB image. Note this is 1 pixel taller than
     *            the image passed to {@link #trace(BufferedImage)} (the extra
     *            row is empty).
     */
    protected void createPixelMask(int[] pixels, int width, int height) {
        for (int k = 0; k < pixels.length; k++) {
            int alpha = (pixels[k] >> 24) & 0xff;
            if (alpha > 250) {
                pixels[k] = PIXEL_INCLUDE;
            } else {
                pixels[k] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Trace a path from start to finish. The starting pixel (x,y) must have a
     * EDGE_TOP flag. As the path is traced (which constructs the Polygon return
     * value) this method also unsets the EDGE_TOP and EDGE_LEFT flags from each
     * pixel it iterates over.
     *
     * @param pixels
     *            the image data. This method relies on each pixel having a
     *            combination of EDGE_TOP and EDGE_LEFT flags set correctly.
     * @param width
     *            the width of the image represented by "pixels"
     * @param height
     *            the height of the image represented by "pixels"
     * @param startX
     *            the initial x-value to start tracing at
     * @param startY
     *            the initial y-value to start tracing at
     * @return a Polygon representing the traced path.
     */
    private Polygon tracePath(int[] pixels, int width, int height, int startX,
                              int startY) {
        Polygon returnValue = new CollapsedPolygon();
        int x = startX;
        int y = startY;
        int edge = EDGE_TOP;
        boolean increment = true;
        while (true) {
            if (edge == EDGE_TOP) {
                if (increment) {
                    returnValue.addPoint(x, y);
                    returnValue.addPoint(x + 1, y);
                } else {
                    returnValue.addPoint(x + 1, y);
                    returnValue.addPoint(x, y);
                }
            } else if (edge == EDGE_LEFT) {
                if (increment) {
                    returnValue.addPoint(x, y);
                    returnValue.addPoint(x, y + 1);
                } else {
                    returnValue.addPoint(x, y + 1);
                    returnValue.addPoint(x, y);
                }
            }
            pixels[y * width + x] ^= edge;

            if (edge == EDGE_TOP) {
                if (increment) {
                    // on a top edge, we just scanned from left-to-right:
                    if (y - 1 >= 0 && x + 1 < width
                            && (pixels[(y - 1) * width + x + 1]
                            & EDGE_LEFT) > 0) {
                        // turn counterclockwise
                        y--;
                        x++;
                        edge = EDGE_LEFT;
                        increment = false;
                    } else if (x + 1 < width
                            && (pixels[y * width + x + 1] & EDGE_TOP) > 0) {
                        // go straight
                        x++;
                        edge = EDGE_TOP;
                        increment = true;
                    } else if (x + 1 < width
                            && (pixels[y * width + x + 1] & EDGE_LEFT) > 0) {
                        // turn clockwise
                        x++;
                        edge = EDGE_LEFT;
                        increment = true;
                    } else {
                        return returnValue;
                    }
                } else {
                    // on a top edge, we just scanned from right-to-left:
                    if ((pixels[y * width + x] & EDGE_LEFT) > 0) {
                        // turn counterclockwise
                        edge = EDGE_LEFT;
                        increment = true;
                    } else if (x - 1 >= 0
                            && (pixels[y * width + x - 1] & EDGE_TOP) > 0) {
                        // go straight
                        x--;
                        edge = EDGE_TOP;
                        increment = false;
                    } else if (y - 1 >= 0
                            && (pixels[(y - 1) * width + x] & EDGE_LEFT) > 0) {
                        // turn clockwise
                        y--;
                        edge = EDGE_LEFT;
                        increment = false;
                    } else {
                        return returnValue;
                    }
                }
            } else if (edge == EDGE_LEFT) {
                if (increment) {
                    // on a left edge, we just scanned from top-to-bottom:
                    if (y + 1 < height
                            && (pixels[(y + 1) * width + x] & EDGE_TOP) > 0) {
                        // turn counterclockwise
                        y++;
                        edge = EDGE_TOP;
                        increment = true;
                    } else if (y + 1 < height
                            && (pixels[(y + 1) * width + x] & EDGE_LEFT) > 0) {
                        // go straight
                        y++;
                        edge = EDGE_LEFT;
                        increment = true;
                    } else if (x - 1 >= 0 && y + 1 < height
                            && (pixels[(y + 1) * width + x - 1]
                            & EDGE_TOP) > 0) {
                        // turn clockwise
                        y++;
                        x--;
                        edge = EDGE_TOP;
                        increment = false;
                    } else {
                        return returnValue;
                    }
                } else {
                    // on a left edge, we just scanned from bottom-to-top:
                    if (x - 1 >= 0
                            && (pixels[y * width + x - 1] & EDGE_TOP) > 0) {
                        // turn counterclockwise
                        x--;
                        edge = EDGE_TOP;
                        increment = false;
                    } else if (y - 1 >= 0
                            && (pixels[(y - 1) * width + x] & EDGE_LEFT) > 0) {
                        // go straight
                        y--;
                        edge = EDGE_LEFT;
                        increment = false;
                    } else if ((pixels[y * width + x] & EDGE_TOP) > 0) {
                        // turn clockwise
                        edge = EDGE_TOP;
                        increment = true;
                    } else {
                        return returnValue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

